# Fixtures not found pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, fixtures

Why fixtures not found when I try to run test if pytest should find automatically functions with name 'test_'?

conftest.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


@pytest.fixture
def driver():
    driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

form_test.py

```
from pages.form_page import FormPage
from conftest import driver


class TestFormPage:
    def test_form(self, driver):
        form_page = FormPage(driver, 'https://www.blabla.com/')
        form_page.open()
```

form_page.py

```
from pages.base_page import BasePage


class FormPage(BasePage):

    def fill_fields_and_submit(self):
        pass
```

base_page.py

```
class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, driver, url):
        self.driver = driver
        self.url = url

    def open(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
```

Working only if I will import driver in file "form_test.py"